# AWS Boto3 SQS endpoint URL issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

We have a Lambda function that sends messages to SQS queue.
We are using boto3.

We have built a new environment and Lambda is running in a VPC on a private subnet.
The VPC end point is com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.sqs

Lambda code

```
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
# Get the queue

queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=QueueID)
```

This gives us the following error
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://eu-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/"

We have tried the following change

```
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
# Get the queue
queue = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName=QueueID, QueueOwnerAWSAccountId='xxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

We get the same error

It is a legacy endpoint issue but we do not know how to use the new endpoints in the Lambda function.

Comment: When you use lambdas in a private VPC, they have no idea where to go. You either need to create a NAT Gateway and allow this lambda access to the internet, or enable a VPC endpoint for the SQS service and setup routes accordingly.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this AWS Lambda function was placed into a VPC (eg to access a database in the same VPC)? If not, then simply remove the Lambda function from the VPC and it will be connected to the Internet. No VPC Endpoint required.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using a VPC endpoint for SQS you need to override the address that boto3 is using by default.

Something like this:

```
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', endpoint_url="https://com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.sqs")
```

Comment: the new endpoint url, with recent changes as follows: endpoint_url="https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"

Comment: @Viji I get `[ERROR] ValueError: Invalid endpoint: sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: you must have not added it to VPC configuration for SQS service